# how to loop thorough a listing in selenium webdriver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to loop through a directory which contains a list of companies. I have written this code in selenium which will just open one link. I want to open like each link in a new tab and scrape some info.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page

link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("h2 > a")
links.click()
```

How ever this code this not open the next link. When i try to loop through the link.click() it gives me a error like "cannot iterate through web element"

Kind of newbie to selenium web driver. can somebody help me out in enhancing the code for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `find_element_by_css_selector` use `find_elements_by_css_selector`. This allows for selecting multiple elements.

And then use a `for` loop to iterate.

```
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

To open the link in a new tab instead of `link.click()` use `link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)`.

There are no direct methods to open new tabs or to traverse between them. You'll have to browser's keyboard shortcuts to work on it.

For docs of `find_elements_by_css_selector`, refer [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector).

Comment: Okay got that right... There's one more thing which i wanna do, open the link in which i have copied in links in a new tab and do some web scraping on it. Problem is that i'm not able to open the link to in the new tab. Plenty of links available to open a blank tab. But no resources available to open a link.

Comment: @PythonLearner - To open the link in a new tab try `link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)` instead of `link.click()`.

Comment: @JRodDynamite here is my question. can you please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232248/how-to-put-mulitple-value-in-loop-and-result-to-csv-python-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Using `link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("h2 > a")` will return you only one element to get list of elements you should use `links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")`.
And then iterate over it.

Please find below the complete answer for both queries:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

driver.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page
parent_tab = driver.current_window_handle
print parent_tab

links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")

for link in links:
    body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
    body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
    driver.get(link.get_attribute('href'))
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.NUMPAD1)
    driver.switch_to_window(parent_tab)
```