# How to put mulitple value in loop and result to csv python selenium

Tags: python, csv, selenium, for-loop

Actually i want to get the value from [here](https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=categorytree). Getting product hyper link is working fine. i want to get product information, price etc.. from above link in same in for loop. How to put result data into CSV file. please help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles")

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[3]/div/div/a""").click()
delay = 20 # seconds
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")))
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print("Page is ready")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time")

time.sleep(10)
for post in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1UoZlX"):
    print(post.get_attribute("href"))
time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

> Output:

```
Page is ready
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-g5-plus-fine-gold-32-gb/p/itmes2zjvwfncxxr?pid=MOBEQHMGED7F9CZ2&srno=b_1_1&otracker=browse
&lid=LSTMOBEQHMGED7F9CZ2KHTBI8
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-g5-plus-lunar-grey-32-gb/p/itmes2zjvwfncxxr?pid=MOBEQHMGMAUXS5BF&srno=b_1_2&otracker=brows
e&lid=LSTMOBEQHMGMAUXS5BFVCF0ZO
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-e3-power-black-16-gb/p/itmekgt2fbywqgcv?pid=MOBEKGT2HGDGADFW&srno=b_1_3&otracker=browse&li
d=LSTMOBEKGT2HGDGADFWP5NHBY
https://www.flipkart.com/micromax-bolt-q381-plus-coffee-16-gb/p/itmeskgycnfghsat?pid=MOBESAMDG2GNUBC5&srno=b_1_4&otracke
r=browse&lid=LSTMOBESAMDG2GNUBC5KRPH8Q
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-k6-power-grey-dark-grey-32-gb/p/itmezenfhm4mvptw?pid=MOBEZENFZBPW8UMF&srno=b_1_5&otracke
r=browse&lid=LSTMOBEZENFZBPW8UMF7P8NY0
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-k6-power-gold-32-gb/p/itmezenfhm4mvptw?pid=MOBEZEMYH7FQBGBQ&srno=b_1_6&otracker=browse&l
id=LSTMOBEZEMYH7FQBGBQRHVU0S
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-k6-power-silver-32-gb/p/itmezenfhm4mvptw?pid=MOBEZEMX6CZHCJVY&srno=b_1_7&otracker=browse
&lid=LSTMOBEZEMX6CZHCJVYOIBM0E
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-note-grey-64-gb/p/itmepcfqfdx9bdxs?pid=MOBEPCFQRJ6KFYZS&srno=b_1_8&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBEPCFQRJ6KFYZSI4DRRB
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-note-gold-64-gb/p/itmepcfqfdx9bdxs?pid=MOBEPCFQ3ZSYTRUZ&srno=b_1_9&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBEPCFQ3ZSYTRUZGFSZCU
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-nxt-gold-32-gb/p/itmemzd4gepexjya?pid=MOBEMZD4KHRF5VZX&srno=b_1_10&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBEMZD4KHRF5VZX7FNU5S
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-e3-power-white-16-gb/p/itmekgt23fgwdgkg?pid=MOBEKGT2SVHPAHTM&srno=b_1_11&otracker=browse&l
id=LSTMOBEKGT2SVHPAHTMJA8RQ1
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-k6-power-silver-32-gb/p/itmezenfghddrfmc?pid=MOBEZENFKXZ4HSCG&srno=b_1_12&otracker=brows
e&lid=LSTMOBEZENFKXZ4HSCGC1OOAM
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-k6-power-gold-32-gb/p/itmezenfghddrfmc?pid=MOBEZENFSZGTQGWF&srno=b_1_13&otracker=browse&
lid=LSTMOBEZENFSZGTQGWFUR1LY1
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-k6-power-dark-gray-32-gb/p/itmezenfghddrfmc?pid=MOBEZENFG8BPDPSU&srno=b_1_14&otracker=br
owse&lid=LSTMOBEZENFG8BPDPSUUANLO6
https://www.flipkart.com/lava-arc-blue/p/itmezgyfszhmwfzt?pid=MOBEF6D24ZT6YHFJ&srno=b_1_15&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEF6
D24ZT6YHFJZ6N7XC
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-plus-3-gb-silver-16-gb/p/itmektn3t9rg9hnn?pid=MOBEKEF8ATFZZ8GN&srno=b_1_16&otrac
ker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEKEF8ATFZZ8GNY7WZBU
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-plus-3-gb-gold-16-gb/p/itmektn3t9rg9hnn?pid=MOBEKEF8JYGKZCTF&srno=b_1_17&otracke
r=browse&lid=LSTMOBEKEF8JYGKZCTFUTCYS4
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-plus-3-gb-dark-grey-16-gb/p/itmektn3t9rg9hnn?pid=MOBEKEF86VVUE8G2&srno=b_1_18&ot
racker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEKEF86VVUE8G2YCW5OP
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-nxt-black-32-gb/p/itmemzd4byrufyu7?pid=MOBEMZD4G83T5HKZ&srno=b_1_19&otracker=bro
wse&lid=LSTMOBEMZD4G83T5HKZVMFKK6
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on8-gold-16-gb/p/itmemvarkqg5dyay?pid=MOBEMJR2NDM4EAHQ&srno=b_1_20&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBEMJR2NDM4EAHQ8BMJIN
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on7-black-8-gb/p/itmedhx3jgmu2gps?pid=MOBECCA5SMRSKCNY&srno=b_1_21&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBECCA5SMRSKCNYWC8DYC
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on7-gold-8-gb/p/itmedhx3jgmu2gps?pid=MOBECCA5Y5HBYR3Q&srno=b_1_22&otracker=brows
e&lid=LSTMOBECCA5Y5HBYR3QPDPGLJ
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on5-gold-8-gb/p/itmedhx3uy3qsfks?pid=MOBECCA5FHQD43KA&srno=b_1_23&otracker=brows
e&lid=LSTMOBECCA5FHQD43KAFXOZYB
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-p2-gold-32-gb/p/itmeq5ygvgq9vyfn?pid=MOBEZFHHURMWYSFN&srno=b_1_24&otracker=browse&lid=LS
TMOBEZFHHURMWYSFNBBG6L0
https://www.flipkart.com/asus-zenfone-max-black-32-gb/p/itmege3d5pjpmknc?pid=MOBEGE3DYZM3ZYWB&srno=b_1_25&otracker=brows
e&lid=LSTMOBEGE3DYZM3ZYWBPCOZHP
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-note-grey-32-gb/p/itmejj6kmhh2khk9?pid=MOBEJJ6KYARZGWJC&srno=b_1_26&otracker=bro
wse&lid=LSTMOBEJJ6KYARZGWJCCV4LRX
https://www.flipkart.com/swipe-elite-sense-4g-volte/p/itmeh6yfycypxfdz?pid=MOBEH6YFZYZZNCZK&srno=b_1_27&otracker=browse&
lid=LSTMOBEH6YFZYZZNCZKWVY6ES
https://www.flipkart.com/swipe-elite-sense-4g-volte/p/itmeh6yfycypxfdz?pid=MOBEH6YFZRTEMDBG&srno=b_1_28&otracker=browse&
lid=LSTMOBEH6YFZRTEMDBGYJNCJI
https://www.flipkart.com/xolo-era-1x-4g-volte-black-gun-metal-8-gb/p/itmerhq8uhtehukg?pid=MOBEHMEKGCZCGMB8&srno=b_1_29&o
tracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEHMEKGCZCGMB8DCWHIY
https://www.flipkart.com/swipe-konnect-grand-black-8-gb/p/itmeqcgxvkyfzsgj?pid=MOBEQCGXN6HTZE2C&srno=b_1_30&otracker=bro
wse&lid=LSTMOBEQCGXN6HTZE2CXUT5W1
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-vibe-k5-note-gold-32-gb/p/itmejj6kczvxej4g?pid=MOBEJJ6K5A3GQ9SU&srno=b_1_31&otracker=bro
wse&lid=LSTMOBEJJ6K5A3GQ9SUZERSAR
https://www.flipkart.com/lyf-water-f1-black-32-gb/p/itmezh76z9jqsa8z?pid=MOBEZH76AFWSZVNH&srno=b_1_32&otracker=browse&li
d=LSTMOBEZH76AFWSZVNHOOBURN
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-black-16-gb/p/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWHJDWMQDF&srno=b
_1_33&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEG4XWHJDWMQDFZIWO93
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-white-16-gb/p/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWJG7F9A6Z&srno=b
_1_34&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEG4XWJG7F9A6ZHJOVBG
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j5-6-new-2016-edition-gold-16-gb/p/itmegmrnzqjcpfg9?pid=MOBEG4XWFTBRMMBY&srno=b_
1_35&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEG4XWFTBRMMBYZPYEGS
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-m-grey-64-gb/p/itmenqavgcezzk2y?pid=MOBENQATHQTKG7AV&srno=b_1_36&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMO
BENQATHQTKG7AVGFQI4N
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-m-gold-64-gb/p/itmenqavgcezzk2y?pid=MOBENQAVANRMEGAP&srno=b_1_37&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMO
BENQAVANRMEGAPHWU47I
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-m-silver-64-gb/p/itmenqavgcezzk2y?pid=MOBENQAVFTG6FPXX&srno=b_1_38&otracker=browse&lid=LST
MOBENQAVFTG6FPXXHZBIGV
https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6-silver-16-gb/p/itme8dvfeuxxbm4r?pid=MOBEYHZ2NUZGCHKN&srno=b_1_39&otracker=browse
&lid=LSTMOBEYHZ2NUZGCHKN7PMDIN
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on8-black-16-gb/p/itmemvarprh8hegn?pid=MOBEMJRFZXZBESQW&srno=b_1_40&otracker=bro
wse&lid=LSTMOBEMJRFZXZBESQWCFHWJ0
https://www.flipkart.com/panasonic-eluga-tapp-silver-grey-16-gb/p/itmezf54ey3gf8ne?pid=MOBENRHGWZWKEGGF&srno=b_1_41&otra
cker=browse&lid=LSTMOBENRHGWZWKEGGFMJELY2
https://www.flipkart.com/panasonic-eluga-tapp-champagne-gold-16-gb/p/itmezf54ey3gf8ne?pid=MOBENRHGEQEJHSZM&srno=b_1_42&o
tracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBENRHGEQEJHSZMD8R5FE
https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6s-rose-gold-32-gb/p/itmen2yymnfcrxsz?pid=MOBEN2XYK8WFEGM8&srno=b_1_43&otracker=br
owse&lid=LSTMOBEN2XYK8WFEGM8QJW5XA
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-p2-grey-graphite-grey-32-gb/p/itmeq5ygvgq9vyfn?pid=MOBEZFHH2JYGXSNF&srno=b_1_44&otracker
=browse&lid=LSTMOBEZFHH2JYGXSNFNWKEAD
https://www.flipkart.com/forme-n1/p/itmeff8s2hdrfhyg?pid=MOBEFF8SHZPYKCRY&srno=b_1_45&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEFF8SHZP
YKCRYEKQPPR
https://www.flipkart.com/forme-n1/p/itmeff8s2hdrfhyg?pid=MOBEFF8SSZNHCUND&srno=b_1_46&otracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBEFF8SSZN
HCUNDRC6GLT
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-on5-black-8-gb/p/itmekszmsqgpgygy?pid=MOBECCA5BJUVUGNP&srno=b_1_47&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBECCA5BJUVUGNPRKEGMG
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-p2-grey-graphite-grey-32-gb/p/itmeq5ygebzgqgfb?pid=MOBEZFHHVD8KXE7G&srno=b_1_48&otracker
=browse&lid=LSTMOBEZFHHVD8KXE7GB0OS6I
https://www.flipkart.com/lenovo-p2-gold-32-gb/p/itmeq5ygebzgqgfb?pid=MOBEZFHHGE2RXQUY&srno=b_1_49&otracker=browse&lid=LS
TMOBEZFHHGE2RXQUY2XDB97
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-j7-gold-16-gb/p/itmeafbfjhsydbpw?pid=MOBE93GWSMGZHFSK&srno=b_1_50&otracker=brows
e&lid=LSTMOBE93GWSMGZHFSKT6OZOB
https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-z2-gold-8-gb/p/itmenkygvprd5dwt?pid=MOBENKYGHFUHT6BH&srno=b_1_51&otracker=browse&lid=LS
TMOBENKYGHFUHT6BHVSHMDE
https://www.flipkart.com/leeco-le-2-grey-32-gb/p/itmejeucxaxmnk8k?pid=MOBEJFTH4C9Z2YZR&srno=b_1_52&otracker=browse&lid=L
STMOBEJFTH4C9Z2YZRVVL0EL
https://www.flipkart.com/lyf-water-10-black-16-gb/p/itmemj7d8qfkfu4r?pid=MOBEMJ7C7YMDMVDQ&srno=b_1_53&otracker=browse&li
d=LSTMOBEMJ7C7YMDMVDQPCFALX
https://www.flipkart.com/micromax-canvas-nitro-2-grey-silver-16-gb/p/itme7nhzw56hv2ga?pid=MOBE7NHZP7GHZ7SG&srno=b_1_54&o
tracker=browse&lid=LSTMOBE7NHZP7GHZ7SGCYGNI3
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-turbo-white-16-gb/p/itmecc4uhbue7ve6?pid=MOBECC4UQTJ5QZFR&srno=b_1_55&otracker=browse&li
d=LSTMOBECC4UQTJ5QZFR9CAUPO
https://www.flipkart.com/moto-g-turbo-black-16-gb/p/itmecc4uhbue7ve6?pid=MOBECC4UZTSGKWWZ&srno=b_1_56&otracker=browse&li
d=LSTMOBECC4UZTSGKWWZOQKAIZ
https://www.flipkart.com/apple-iphone-6-space-grey-16-gb/p/itme8dvfeuxxbm4r?pid=MOBEYHZ2YAXZMF2J&srno=b_1_57&otracker=br
owse&lid=LSTMOBEYHZ2YAXZMF2JEVWVNC
https://www.flipkart.com/yu-yunicorn-rush-silver-32-gb/p/itmenffyjfp8ubyg?pid=MOBEJ3MFUQAF8XJS&srno=b_1_58&otracker=brow
se&lid=LSTMOBEJ3MFUQAF8XJSBPC8L4
https://www.flipkart.com/yu-yunicorn-gold-rush-32-gb/p/itmenffyjfp8ubyg?pid=MOBEJ3MF23Q9MGMH&srno=b_1_59&otracker=browse
&lid=LSTMOBEJ3MF23Q9MGMHZ49MG2
https://www.flipkart.com/micromax-canvas-nitro-2-white-gold-16-gb/p/itme7nhzw56hv2ga?pid=MOBE8TJBHGQYHNPT&srno=b_1_60&ot
racker=browse&lid=LSTMOBE8TJBHGQYHNPTVL3HS0
```

Answer (score 0):

Used openpyxl to create a csv for each run with the filename+timestamp. Links that are fetched are written to the csv file eventually.
I couldn't find the exact links that have been given and hence I chose my own links which are similar in case. This code has different links per se, but the solution scales up to be same for your case @venkatesh

One more thing: Try to keep xpaths as relative as possible, and the classes with such gibberish as `_13oc-S` Would not hold good as they tend to change dynamically for each DOM refresh or each browser instance.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import openpyxl

current_time = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
xlpath = "linktracker" + current_time + ".csv"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles")
driver.maximize_window()

# Searches for a certain brand of phpnes (POCO). Inefficient way of locator finding though
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//*[@alt='Shop Now'])[2]").click()
time.sleep(10)  # bad practice, but used for now. Webdriverwait to be used instead.
each_element = "//a[@rel='noopener noreferrer']"  # locates each desired element in the search page (each phone block)
posts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, each_element)
print(len(posts))
ls=[]
for post in range(len(posts)-1):  # len-1 because the last item is a footer and not the desired link in my view
    # concatanates the subscript to element xpath: e.g.: (//*[@element = 'ele'])[1] ... (//*[@element = 'ele'])[n]
    each_post = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(' + each_element + ')' + '[' + str(post + 1) + ']')
    each_link = each_post.get_attribute("href")
    ls.append(each_link)

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()  # creates a workbook
sheet = wb.active
c=0
# looping through the created list and writing the values to the created workbook
for i in ls:
    sheet.cell(row=c+1, column=1).value = i
    c+=1  # incrementing the row for each iteration of i
wb.save(xlpath)  # saving the workbook with the name as given in the xlpath variable above
driver.quit()
```

[Result in csv - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRAGc.png)